# Set axis limits across faceted plot

Tags: python, pandas

How can I fix the x-axis on each of the plots in the following situation? Using `xlim` only affects the second plot axis, not both.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sample = pd.DataFrame({'mean':[1,2,3,4,5], 'median':[10,20,30,40,50]})

sample.hist()
plt.xlim(0, 100)
```

Bonus, what is the correct pandas terminology for the two plots here? Subplots? Facets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct terminology would be **subplot** or **axes** since `hist` returns the matplotlib axis instances:

```
axes = sample.hist()
for ax in axes.ravel():
    ax.set_xlim(0,100)
```

Output:

[image]